# ICFPC 2006 task on Haskell is too slow

Tags: performance, haskell

I am learning Haskell, and as a task for myself I was trying to implement [a Universal Machine from ICFP Contest 2006](http://www.boundvariable.org/um-spec.txt). I came up with a code, which, at a first glance, seems to be working. However, when I try to execute any application for that Universal Machine provided on [the contest's website](http://www.boundvariable.org/task.shtml) (e.g. sandmark.umz), my implementation is too slow to actually run anything. Self-check did not finish in a couple of hours, and I had to kill the process. So, I am clearly doing something wrong, I just don't know what.

I have tried to use Haskell's profiler, but I couldn't make any sense out of those numbers as well. Garbage collection doesn't seem to be taking a lot of time (3 seconds out of 173 seconds of a sample). However, total allocated memory during those 173 seconds was almost 6 GB, while the maximum heap size was 13 MB.

Could you help me understand, what is wrong with my code? I know that the amount of code is quite large, but I am not sure how to come up with a minimum reproducible example in my case, when I don't really know what is relevant, and what is not. Thank you.

```
module Main where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.Exit (exitSuccess)
import System.IO (hPutStrLn, stderr)
import System.IO.Error (catchIOError)
import Control.Monad (when)
import Control.Monad.Loops (iterateM_)
import Data.Array.IO (IOUArray, newArray, newListArray, readArray, writeArray, mapArray)
import Data.Bits
import Data.Binary.Get (getWord32be, runGet, isEmpty, Get)
import Data.Char (chr, ord)
import Data.Word (Word32)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as M
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import qualified Data.IntSet as IntSet

data UMState = UMState {
    getFinger :: Word32,
    getRegisters :: IOUArray Int Word32,
    getArrays :: M.IntMap (IOUArray Word32 Word32),
    getFreeIds :: [Int],
    getMaxId :: Int,
    getCopiedPlatters :: IntSet.IntSet
}

getOperation :: Word32 -> Int
getOperation x = fromIntegral $ (x `shiftR` 28) .&. 15

getRegisterIds :: Word32 -> (Int, Int, Int)
getRegisterIds x = (fromIntegral $ (x `shiftR` 6) .&. 7, fromIntegral $ (x `shiftR` 3) .&. 7, fromIntegral $ x .&. 7)

getOrthography :: Word32 -> (Int, Word32)
getOrthography x = (fromIntegral $ (x `shiftR` 25) .&. 7, x .&. 33554431)

setFinger :: UMState -> Word32 -> UMState
setFinger (UMState {
        getFinger = _,
        getRegisters = regs,
        getArrays = arr,
        getFreeIds = fids,
        getMaxId = mid,
        getCopiedPlatters = cp
    }) f' = UMState {
        getFinger = f',
        getRegisters = regs,
        getArrays = arr,
        getFreeIds = fids,
        getMaxId = mid,
        getCopiedPlatters = cp
}

removePlatter :: UMState -> Int -> UMState
removePlatter (UMState {
        getFinger = f,
        getRegisters = regs,
        getArrays = arr,
        getFreeIds = fids,
        getMaxId = mid,
        getCopiedPlatters = cp
    }) pid = UMState {
        getFinger = f,
        getRegisters = regs,
        getArrays = M.delete pid arr,
        getFreeIds = (pid:fids),
        getMaxId = mid,
        getCopiedPlatters = cp
}

insertPlatter :: UMState -> Int -> IOUArray Word32 Word32 -> UMState
insertPlatter (UMState {
        getFinger = f,
        getRegisters = regs,
        getArrays = arr,
        getFreeIds = fids@(hfid:tfids),
        getMaxId = mid,
        getCopiedPlatters = cp
    }) pid platter = UMState {
        getFinger = f,
        getRegisters = regs,
        getArrays = M.insert pid platter arr,
        getFreeIds = if pid == hfid then tfids else fids,
        getMaxId = max mid pid,
        getCopiedPlatters = cp
}
insertPlatter (UMState {
        getFinger = f,
        getRegisters = regs,
        getArrays = arr,
        getFreeIds = [],
        getMaxId = mid,
        getCopiedPlatters = cp
    }) pid platter = UMState {
        getFinger = f,
        getRegisters = regs,
        getArrays = M.insert pid platter arr,
        getFreeIds = [],
        getMaxId = max mid pid,
        getCopiedPlatters = cp
}

setCopiedPlatters :: UMState -> IntSet.IntSet -> UMState
setCopiedPlatters (UMState {
        getFinger = f,
        getRegisters = regs,
        getArrays = arr,
        getFreeIds = fids,
        getMaxId = mid,
        getCopiedPlatters = _
    }) copied' = UMState {
        getFinger = f,
        getRegisters = regs,
        getArrays = arr,
        getFreeIds = fids,
        getMaxId = mid,
        getCopiedPlatters = copied'
}

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    fileName <- parseArgs $ filter (\arg -> arg /= "--") args
    platters <- B.readFile fileName
    array0 <- listToArray (runGet readPlatters platters)
    regs <- (newArray (0, 7) 0 :: IO (IOUArray Int Word32))
    let initState = (UMState {
            getFinger = 0,
            getRegisters = regs,
            getArrays = M.insert 0 array0 M.empty,
            getFreeIds = [],
            getMaxId = 0,
            getCopiedPlatters = IntSet.empty
        })
        in iterateM_ spinCycle initState

parseArgs :: [String] -> IO (String)
parseArgs [arg] = return arg
parseArgs args = fail $ "Exactly one argument expected. Found: " ++ (show args)

readPlatters :: Get [Word32]
readPlatters = do
    empty <- isEmpty
    if empty 
        then return []
        else do
            platter <- getWord32be
            theRest <- readPlatters
            return (platter:theRest)

listToArray :: [Word32] -> IO (IOUArray Word32 Word32)
listToArray lst = newListArray (fromIntegral 0, fromIntegral (length lst) - 1) lst

spinCycle :: UMState -> IO (UMState)
spinCycle state = do
    platter <- readArray (fromJust (M.lookup 0 (getArrays state))) (getFinger state)
    let state' = setFinger state $ getFinger state + 1
        (aId, bId, cId) = getRegisterIds platter
        regs = getRegisters state' 
        arrays = getArrays state' in (
            case (getOperation platter) of
                0 -> do
                    runConditionalMove aId bId cId regs
                    return state'
                1 -> do
                    runArrayIndex aId bId cId regs arrays
                    return state'
                2 -> runArrayAmendment aId bId cId state'
                3 -> do
                    runAddition aId bId cId regs
                    return state'
                4 -> do
                    runMultiplication aId bId cId regs
                    return state'
                5 -> do
                    runDivision aId bId cId regs
                    return state'
                6 -> do
                    runNand aId bId cId regs
                    return state'
                7 -> runHalt
                8 -> runAllocation bId cId state'
                9 -> runAbandonment cId state'
                10 -> do
                    runOutput cId regs
                    return state'
                11 -> do
                    runInput cId regs
                    return state'
                12 -> runLoadProgram bId cId state'
                13 -> do
                    let (reg, val) = getOrthography platter
                        in (runOrthography reg val regs)
                    return state'
       )

-- #0. Conditional Move.
runConditionalMove :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IOUArray Int Word32 -> IO ()
runConditionalMove a b c regs = do
    hPutStrLn stderr ("conditionalMove " ++ (show a) ++ " " ++ (show b) ++ " " ++ (show c))
    cRead <- readArray regs c
    when (cRead /= 0) $ do
        bRead <- readArray regs b
        writeArray regs a bRead

-- #1. Array Index.
runArrayIndex :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IOUArray Int Word32 -> M.IntMap (IOUArray Word32 Word32) -> IO ()
runArrayIndex a b c regs arrays = do
    hPutStrLn stderr ("arrayIndex " ++ (show a) ++ " " ++ (show b) ++ " " ++ (show c))
    bRead <- readArray regs b
    cRead <- readArray regs c
    val <- readArray (fromJust (M.lookup (fromIntegral bRead) arrays)) cRead
    writeArray regs a val

-- #2. Array Amendment.
runArrayAmendment :: Int -> Int -> Int -> UMState -> IO (UMState)
runArrayAmendment a b c state = do
    hPutStrLn stderr ("arrayAmendment " ++ (show a) ++ " " ++ (show b) ++ " " ++ (show c))
    aRead <- readArray (getRegisters state) a
    bRead <- readArray (getRegisters state) b
    cRead <- readArray (getRegisters state) c
    stateToWrite <- if IntSet.member (fromIntegral aRead) (getCopiedPlatters state) then (do
        pCopy <- mapArray id (fromJust (M.lookup (fromIntegral aRead) (getArrays state)))
        let state' = insertPlatter state (fromIntegral aRead) pCopy
            state'' = setCopiedPlatters state' $ IntSet.delete (fromIntegral aRead) (getCopiedPlatters state')
            in return state''
        ) else return state
    writeArray (fromJust (M.lookup (fromIntegral aRead) (getArrays stateToWrite))) bRead cRead
    return stateToWrite

-- #3. Addition.
runAddition :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IOUArray Int Word32 -> IO ()
runAddition a b c regs = do
    hPutStrLn stderr ("addition " ++ (show a) ++ " " ++ (show b) ++ " " ++ (show c))
    bRead <- readArray regs b
    cRead <- readArray regs c
    writeArray regs a (bRead + cRead)

-- #4. Multiplication.
runMultiplication :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IOUArray Int Word32 -> IO ()
runMultiplication a b c regs = do
    hPutStrLn stderr ("multiplication " ++ (show a) ++ " " ++ (show b) ++ " " ++ (show c))
    bRead <- readArray regs b
    cRead <- readArray regs c
    writeArray regs a (bRead * cRead)

-- #5. Division.
runDivision :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IOUArray Int Word32 -> IO ()
runDivision a b c regs = do
    hPutStrLn stderr ("division " ++ (show a) ++ " " ++ (show b) ++ " " ++ (show c))
    bRead <- readArray regs b
    cRead <- readArray regs c
    writeArray regs a (bRead `div` cRead)

-- #6. Not-And.
runNand :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IOUArray Int Word32 -> IO ()
runNand a b c regs = do
    hPutStrLn stderr ("nand " ++ (show a) ++ " " ++ (show b) ++ " " ++ (show c))
    bRead <- readArray regs b
    cRead <- readArray regs c
    writeArray regs a (complement $ bRead .&. cRead)

-- #7. Halt.
runHalt = exitSuccess :: IO (UMState)

-- #8. Allocation.
runAllocation :: Int -> Int -> UMState -> IO (UMState)
runAllocation b c state = do
    hPutStrLn stderr ("allocation " ++ (show b) ++ " " ++ (show c))
    cRead <- readArray (getRegisters state) c
    pArray <- (newArray (0, cRead) 0 :: IO (IOUArray Word32 Word32))
    (state', newId) <-
        case (getFreeIds state) of
            (freeId:_) -> return (insertPlatter state freeId pArray, freeId)
            [] -> let maxId' = getMaxId state + 1 in return (insertPlatter state maxId' pArray, maxId')
    writeArray (getRegisters state') b (fromIntegral newId)
    return state'

-- #9. Abandonment.
runAbandonment :: Int -> UMState -> IO (UMState)
runAbandonment c state = do
    hPutStrLn stderr ("abandonment " ++ (show c))
    cRead <- readArray (getRegisters state) c
    return (removePlatter state $ fromIntegral cRead)

-- #10. Output.
runOutput :: Int -> IOUArray Int Word32 -> IO ()
runOutput c regs = do
    cRead <- readArray regs c
    when (cRead < 256) $ putChar . chr . fromIntegral $ cRead

-- #11. Input.
runInput :: Int -> IOUArray Int Word32 -> IO ()
runInput c regs = do
    cRead <- getChar `catchIOError` (\_ -> return $ chr 255)
    writeArray regs c (fromIntegral $ ord cRead)

-- #12. Load Program.
runLoadProgram :: Int -> Int -> UMState -> IO (UMState)
runLoadProgram b c state = do
    hPutStrLn stderr ("loadProgram " ++ (show b) ++ " " ++ (show c))
    bRead <- readArray (getRegisters state) b
    cRead <- readArray (getRegisters state) c
    let bReadInt = fromIntegral bRead
        pCopy = fromJust (M.lookup bReadInt (getArrays state))
        copied = IntSet.insert 0 (getCopiedPlatters state)
        copied' = IntSet.insert bReadInt copied
        state' = insertPlatter state 0 pCopy
        state'' = setFinger state' cRead
        state''' = setCopiedPlatters state'' copied'
        in return state'''

-- #13. Orthography.
runOrthography :: Int -> Word32 -> IOUArray Int Word32 -> IO ()
runOrthography reg val regs = writeArray regs reg val
```

Comment: Your problem is much more likely to be a bug in your code than a performance issue.

Comment: Have you checked your code thoroughly for non-terminations?

Comment: Allocating 6GB with a max of 13MB resident is the mostly-happy path for ghc. Allocation is fast (usually a single instruction), and GC time is proportional to the live set. That's not a cause for concern.

Comment: @AndrewRay Yes, I have thought about the program having an infinite loop somewhere. However, the contest webpage has an expected output for that sandmark.umz, and if I wait long enough, it advances a bit and outputs the next expected line. This leads me to the conclusion that the programs works correctly, but really slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total allocation of 3 gigabytes for a Haskell programming running for 176 seconds is miniscule.  Most Haskell programs allocate 3-6 gigabytes per second for their entire runtime.  In your case, much of the program is running in tight, allocation-free loops (generally a good thing when you're trying to write a fast program), which may explain the small amount of allocation.  The small proportion of time spent garbage collecting is also a good sign.

I tested your program on `sandmark.umz` and`codex.umz`, built with `-O2` and no profiling.

I believe the main problem is that the `hPutStrLn` logging lines are generating tons of output, so your universal machine is spending all its time writing logs.

Comment out all the `hPutStrLn` lines, and SANDmark prints a line every few seconds.  I have no idea how fast it's supposed to be, but it's certainly running.

For Codex, it completes the `self-check succeeded` in a few seconds and accepts a 32-character key.  If you enter the wrong key, it prints "wrong key".  If you enter the right key, it prints "decrypting..."  At this point, it seems to freeze up, so I suspect your implementation *is* too slow, but not nearly as slow as you were reporting.

Note that you may find it helpful to turn off buffering on `stdin` and `stdout` at the start of `main`:

```
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    ...
```

so that the `getChar` and `putChar`-based I/O operate immediately.  This isn't strictly necessary, but might help avoid apparent lockups that are actually just buffering issues.

Comment: Also, profiling shows that your program is spending almost all its time in `runArrayAmendment` when stuck "decrypting...", so that would be a good place to look for potential performance improvements.